# Escpos thermal printer unique characters character how to generating and printing receipt

Tags: python, node.js, thermal-printer, escpos

I tried to use a escpos package but it doesn't generate unique characters for my language, even with encoding ISO-8859-2 and windows-1250 this same behavior appears with python version

I have already printed a pdf, the printer is able to print a unique character so it seems to be a package problem, as I can not solve a problem with escpos I decided to generate a pdf and then print it, but I am not sure what kind of tools to use I saw a pdf kit but some people advice to use XML.

I am looking for some advice with it or maybe you know how to deal with escpos

Comment: Your question post has little information for others to recognize the problem and reproduce/research/answer. Use these help articles to refine your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)